# C++ -- Assigning a derived class to a base class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, overloading

StackOverflow!

I come from a Java-saturated background and am trying my hand at C++ for the first time.  I am writing a base class to represent a game state (Pause state, Play state, Menu state).  The Engine class will keep a reference to a state object, AKA the current game state, and then call that state's update, render, and pollInput functions during the game loop.

In Java, I would do this like this:

In my Engine class, I would require my current state variable:

```
State currState = new MainMenuState();
```

Then, if I wanted to set the current state to be a Play state, I could just do this:

```
currState = new PlayState();
```

Now, all I would have to do to make sure my engine was calling the correct state's update method is call the current state's update method, which I can do because PlayState, MainMenuState, and all of my other states extend the State class, which has an update method.

```
public void update()
{
currState.update();
}
```

How do I do something like this in C++?  I decided to define all of my derived classes as public inner classes inside of the State class (I like consolidating code).  **Is it bad practice for me to have inner classes extending their outer class?**

I still need to maintain a reference to the current state in my Engine, but I just learned about the slicing problem with assigning a derived class to a base class like this:

```
State currState = new State::MainMenuState();
```

So if I understand correctly, I can't assign a derived class to a base class object in C++ the way I can in Java.  **So how do I keep one object that can possibly hold values representing all of the different derived classes?**

Please let me know if you need more information from me.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: std::shared_ptr<State> currState = ...;

Comment: What is a shared_ptr?  Sorry, hope you don't mind my asking.  I'm quite new to C++.  What advantages does using a shared_ptr confer over a regular pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you only encounter slicing problem if you're copying the object. In order to achieve what you want, you should use pointers and virtual methods. If you're assigning derrived class' object pointer to base class pointer, you're ok. So `State* currState = new State::MainMenuState();` should work just fine.

Or as someone commented a more modern approach would be to use shared pointers: `std::shared_ptr<State> currState = std::make_shared<State::MainMenuState>();`. `std::shared_pointer` encapsulates naked pointer and does reference counting.

Comment: Oh wait, if you have the time... I'm having a problem when I try this, I get the error message "No viable conversion from 'shared_ptr<class State::MainMenuState>' to 'shared_ptr<class State>'".  Could I have done something wrong with my inheritance?

in my .h file, I just declared the class MainMenuState as public.  It does not inherit from anything.  In the .cpp I specified that "class MainMenuState :: public State".  Is this incorrect?

Comment: No. You must specify inheritance in class declaration in header file. `class MainMenuState : public State { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @PovilasB's answer, you also asked about inner classes. You can use inner classes in C++, but it's not as common as in Java. Personally I don't remember the last time I used an inner class in C++.